How to add a project to neo4j AuraDB cloud offering?
I've started using auradb, and trying to add a second project(or tenant in the old console), but I cant find the button for adding a new project.
Am I missing something?

You can only create one AuraDB Free instance per account

It's a professional paid plan, and I'm talking about projects/tenants, one level above instances.
